# Can not see drive in Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote, connection, desktop, drive

I did an upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 7. Since I did that I can not see my drive. Of course I set the local ressources settings and the remote settings. The operating system on my server is Windows 2008 R2. I did the remote session with the same settings in Windows XP and that works fine. Does someone know where I change any settings to see my local C drive on my remote desktop?

Comment: Are you definitely logging off the server, rather than disconnecting?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes some users have 2 sessions (even limit is set to 1). This COULD cause this problem.

Try logging into the server as admin, go to admin tools, RDS, remote session manager, and log off the user that is disconnected. Then when the user logs in again, the local drives show up.